# Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:

Tags: contract-development

I'm calling an ethereum contract function with the following inputs. However it returns an error saying the numbers are not a base 16 number.

Code

`function checkResult(string str1, uint num1, uint num2) public returns (bytes){
// do something`

Geth Input

`testcontract.checkResult("test",4,21);`

Error

`Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number: 
    at L (bignumber.js:3:2876)
    at bignumber.js:3:8435
    at a (bignumber.js:3:389)
    at web3.js:1098:23
    at web3.js:1634:20
    at web3.js:826:16
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:825:12
    at web3.js:4080:18`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?